# How to use sessions in php with multiple fields?

Tags: php, session, authentication

So I have multiple fields stored in session variable. When I use them in other pages, it won't work. Error says unidentified index. The flow goes like this. index.php which is my login page passes values to getlogin.php then it redirects it to index_s.php where i need to display the user who is logged in. here's the code

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Signin</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/local.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">V-cart</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i> Sign in</a></li>
                    <li><a href="register.php"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Register</a></li>
                    
                   </ul>
                
            </div>
        </nav>

            <div class="container">    
        <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">                    
            <div class="panel panel-info" >
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
                        <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#"></a></div>
                    </div>     

                    <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >

                        <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>
                            
                        <form action="getlogin.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="getlogin" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                    
                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                        <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="username or email">                                        
                                    </div>
                                
                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
                                    </div>
                                    

                                
                            <div class="input-group">
                                      <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                          <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                                        </label>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>


                                <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                                    <!-- Button -->

                                    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                      <button input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-info"/>Login  </a>
                                      
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                        <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" >
                                            Don't have an account! 
                                        <a href="register.php">
Register
                                        </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
                            </form>     



                        </div>                     
                    </div>  
        </div>
         
    </div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

getlogin.php

```html
<?php



session_start();
define('DB_NAME', 'userdb');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("userdb");

if (!$db_selected) {
 die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}


$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

 $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE(
     username='".$user."' or emailaddress='".$user."' and  password='".$pass."')";


 
      $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
   
if($result[0]>0)
{
 
 
 $_SESSION['isvalid'] = true ; 
 $_SESSION['susername']=$user;
 $_SESSION['suid'] = $result['uid'];
 $_SESSION['semail'] = $reult['emailaddress'];
 $_SESSION['sfirstname'] = $reult['firstname'];
 $_SESSION['slastname'] = $reult['lastname'];
 
 header('Location: index_s.php');
}
else
{
 header('Location: index2.php');
 
}
 

mysql_close();
?>
```

index_s.php

```html
<?php  session_start();  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Timeline </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/local.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   

      
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="timeline.php">V-cart</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li><a href="timeline.php"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Timeline</a></li>          
     <li><a href="request.php"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Request Ad</a></li>
                    <li><a href="post.php"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Post Ad</a></li>
                    
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-user">
                    <li class="dropdown messages-dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Messages <span class="badge"></span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">No Messages</li>
                            <li class="message-preview">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="avatar"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></span>
                                    <span class="message">Security alert</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="message-preview">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="avatar"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></span>
                                    <span class="message">Security alert</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Go to Inbox <span class="badge"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown user-dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <?php echo $_SESSION['susername'] ;  ?><b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="profileme.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Settings</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

         <hr />
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1 id="timeline">User Events</h1>
            </div>
            
   
   
   <?php




define('DB_NAME', 'userdb');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("userdb");

if (!$db_selected) {
 die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM postad";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$link);

$count = "SELECT count(bid) FROM postad";
$record= mysql_fetch_array($myData);



mysql_close();
?>
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   <ul class="timeline">
                
    
    
   
    
    <li>
                    <div class="timeline-badge info"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i></div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title"><?php echo $record['title'];  ?></h4>                            
                            <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i></span>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
Author : <?php echo $record['author'];  ?> <br>
Semester : <?php echo $record['semester'];  ?> <br>
Details: <?php echo $record['description'];  ?> <br>



</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
    
    
    
                <li class="timeline-inverted">
                    <div class="timeline-badge success"><i class="fa fa-unlock"></i></div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="timeline-heading">
                            <h4 class="timeline-title">Book 2</h4>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i> 57 minutes ago</span>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                        <div class="timeline-body">
                             <p>Details</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
   
   
   
        </div> 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm just displaying username who is logged in index_s.php on line
echo $_SESSION['susername'];
In all three, i never used destroysession but still it says unidentified index. Is this the correct way I am using session?

Comment: Not an answer, but learn to hash passwords, use prepared statements in sql and prevent XSS. As it currently is your application is one bug security hole.

Comment: thanks for the reply

Comment: Can you explain your problem briefly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cannot see anything wrong with your session, but are you sure it Sets them in the first place?

Try echoing them right after you set them.

Also try using `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {` instead of `if($result[0]>0) {`

Also you have spelling error when getting your resultset

$_SESSION['semail'] = `$reult`['emailaddress']; shoul be $result, the same applies to some of the other lines :)

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for the reply. I dont know this is a bug or something, but I figured it out with your help. seems like $result['any'] assiging to session variable doesnt work. though i ran the code without spelling mistake but i got same error. when i put value of $result[] into a variable then into session, it worked!